# Sort chunks of rows sequentially of multiple input files using a pattern match

Tags: for-loop, awk, pattern-matching

I have chunks of data spread across 100 files that when re-sorted follows a numerical sequence. For instance, if I have 100 chunks of data, chunk #1, 3, 5 could be in one file and chunk #2, 4, 6 could be in another. I need to create 1 output file with all the chunks in sequential order: #1,2,3,4,5,6.

Below is a shortened version of 2 (of the 100) input files. Each chunk begins with "ITEM: TIMESTEP" and needs to be organized by the number in the following line (here that's 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000).

INPUT FILE 1

> **ITEM: TIMETEP**
>   1000
>   ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
>   50 2 H 0.4 0.3 0.006
>   10214 2 H 0.5 0.4 0.002
>   ......#12,000 lines later#...
>   **ITEM: TIMETEP**
>   3000
>   ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
>   50 2 H 2.3 1.4 0.3
>   10214 2 H 2.5 1.3 0.6
>   ......#12,000 lines later#...

INPUT FILE 2

> **ITEM: TIMETEP**
>   2000
>   ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
>   50 2 H 0.4 0.3 0.006
>   10214 2 H 0.5 0.4 0.002
>   ......#12,000 lines later#...
>   **ITEM: TIMETEP**
>   4000
>   ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
>   50 2 H 2.3 1.4 0.3
>   10214 2 H 2.5 1.3 0.6
>   ......#12,000 lines later#...

The final output file would look like this

> ITEM: TIMETEP
>   1000
>   ....#rest of chunk#...
>   ITEM: TIMETEP
>   2000
>   ....#rest of chunk#...
>   ITEM: TIMETEP
>   3000
>   ....#rest of chunk#...
>   ITEM: TIMETEP
>   4000
>   ....#rest of chunk#...

So far, I've inserted an identifier string called "IDENTIFIER" before the start of each chunk:

```
awk -v n=12,000 '1; NR%n==0 {print "IDENTIFIER"}' in.txt >> out1.txt
```

And I can print the N rows needed per each chunk that follows each idenitfier string, looping through multiple files

```
for i in $(seq 1000 1000 10000); do
  awk 'c&&c--;/IDENTIFIER/{c=12,000}' out${i}.txt >> out-final.txt
done
```

I used this method to specifically identify the 2nd row of each chunk because those numbers could be repeated within the chunk itself. However, I don't know how to modify the 2nd command line so that it only prints to out-final.txt when the value after IDENTIFIER is the next number in the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest another approach, first split files so that each item is in its own file, then merge back the files in desired order.  For example for the given two files

```
$ awk '/^ITEM: TIMETEP/{h=$0; next} 
                     h {f="item_"$0; print h > f; h=""} 
                       {print > f}' file1 file2
```

will create the four extracts, which can be merged back, simply

```
$ cat item_{1..4}000 > merged_items
```

Comment: Maybe add `close(f)` before redefining `f`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use perl for this

```
cat file{1,2} | perl -0777 -ne '
    @records = split /^(?=ITEM: TIMETEP)/m;
    print join "",
        map  { $_->[1] }
        sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] }
        map  { ($n) = /\n(\d+)\n/; [$n, $_] }
        @records;
'
```

The `-0777` options forces perl to slurp the entire input into a single string. We use the header to split into records. Then a Schwartzian transform to sort, and join the records together again and print.

---

If you enjoy pain, here's the line-noisy one-liner version:

```
cat file{1,2} | perl -0777 -pe'$_=join"",map{$_->[1]}sort{$a->[0]<=>$b->[0]}map{[/\n(\d+)\n/,$_]}split/^(?=ITEM: TIMETEP)/m'
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefix each record with the record ID from line 2 of each record and the line number since the start of that record, sort on that record ID and line number, then remove them again after the sort:

```
$ cat tst.sh
awk '
    BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
    /^ITEM: TIMETEP/ { head=$0; lineNr=1; next }
    lineNr == 1 { recId=$0; print recId, lineNr, head }
    { print recId, ++lineNr, $0 }
' "$@" |
sort -k1,2n |
cut -f3-

$ ./tst.sh file1 file2
ITEM: TIMETEP
1000
ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
50 2 H 0.4 0.3 0.006
10214 2 H 0.5 0.4 0.002
......#12,000 lines later#...
ITEM: TIMETEP
2000
ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
50 2 H 0.4 0.3 0.006
10214 2 H 0.5 0.4 0.002
......#12,000 lines later#...
ITEM: TIMETEP
3000
ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
50 2 H 2.3 1.4 0.3
10214 2 H 2.5 1.3 0.6
......#12,000 lines later#...
ITEM: TIMETEP
4000
ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
50 2 H 2.3 1.4 0.3
10214 2 H 2.5 1.3 0.6
......#12,000 lines later#...
```

Since the only command above that's processing all of the input "at once" (as opposed to line by line) is `sort` it'll work for large numbers of large files since `sort` is designed to do paging, etc. to handle large input (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279099/133219).